# Get Wearable Activity in Service

Tags: android, android-activity, wear-os

I am porting over a Android app to a android wear app. In the android app the main activity starts a Service and in the service I use MainActivity.activity.  In the wear app I start the same service from WearActivity but Im not able to  find a similar call like MainActivity.activity in the WearActivity. How can I get the parent activity in the Service?

Comment: You may want to check this [Android Wear Docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/android-wear-docs/latest/android-wear-docs.pdf) wherein you can see examples on how to extend your main activity from `WearableActivity` like the one given in enabling the always on feature. For Additional insights, see also this [GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/117b05aad4db251f7534). Hope it will help you.

Comment: What is `MainActivity.activity`? Is it a field in your `Activity` subclass?